# ComplexFilterPart with multiple SimpleFilterPart

Tags: soap-api, ampscript, marketing-cloud

I would like to create a filter like this:  `ET_CREATE_DATE > Now - 6hrs and ET_CREATE_DATE < Now() AND ET_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE > Now - 6hrs and ET_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE < Now()`

This doesn't work:

```
Set @sf1 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"Property","ET_CREATE_DATE")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"SimpleOperator","greaterThan")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf1,"Value",Format(@minusSystemTime,"yyyy-MM-dd"))

Set @sf2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf2,"Property","ET_CREATE_DATE")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf2,"SimpleOperator","lessThan")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf2,"Value",Format(@currentSystemTime,"yyyy-MM-dd"))

Set @sf3 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf3,"Property","ET_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE ")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf3,"SimpleOperator","greaterThan")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf3,"Value",Format(@minusSystemTime,"yyyy-MM-dd"))

Set @sf4 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf4,"Property","ET_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf4,"SimpleOperator","lessThan")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf4,"Value",Format(@currentSystemTime,"yyyy-MM-dd"))

Set @cf1 = CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LeftOperand",@sf1)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"RightOperand",@sf2)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LogicalOperator","AND")
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LeftOperand",@sf3)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"RightOperand",@sf4)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LogicalOperator","AND")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
Set @sf1 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"Property","ET_CREATE_DATE")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf1,"SimpleOperator","greaterThan")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf1,"Value",Format(@minusSystemTime,"yyyy-MM-dd"))

Set @sf2 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf2,"Property","ET_CREATE_DATE")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf2,"SimpleOperator","lessThan")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf2,"Value",Format(@currentSystemTime,"yyyy-MM-dd"))

Set @cf1 = CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LeftOperand",@sf1)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"RightOperand",@sf2)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf1,"LogicalOperator","AND")


Set @sf3 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf3,"Property","ET_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf3,"SimpleOperator","greaterThan")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf3,"Value",Format(@minusSystemTime,"yyyy-MM-dd"))

Set @sf4 = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf4,"Property","ET_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE")
    SetObjectProperty(@sf4,"SimpleOperator","lessThan")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sf4,"Value",Format(@currentSystemTime,"yyyy-MM-dd"))

Set @cf2 = CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart")
    SetObjectProperty(@cf2,"LeftOperand",@sf1)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf2,"RightOperand",@sf2)
    SetObjectProperty(@cf2,"LogicalOperator","AND")

SetObjectProperty(@retrieveRequest, "Filter", @cf1)
SetObjectProperty(@retrieveRequest, "Filter", @cf2)
```